# Capacitor GND to GND on Magnetic Sensor

Tags: capacitor, ground, magnetometer

What is the purpose of this capacitor placement ? 
Why is it placed like that near Magnetic Sensor ?

[image]

Comment: probably specified in the datasheet of the magnetic sensor: the classical decoupling capacitor like you'd find it on any IC's power connection. Might also be a filter bandwidth-defining capacitor. Would be defined in the datasheet. Datasheet. Read. the Datasheet. You should probably read the datasheet! ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller But it looks to me as though both ends of the capacitor are connected to the (ground?) plane. So there doesn't seem to be any electrical function for the capacitor...I think that is the crux of the question.

Comment: probably evens out the effect of the other three components on the sensor

Comment: @ElliotAlderson good point. In an RF application, I'd have assumed that the package is hiding a third contact beneath that is connected to a trace as a passthrough cap. But here, I'll admit I might have been wrong. It would still be super useful to know the type and get the datasheet of the IC, instead of seeing it covered by the tip of tweezers

Comment: @Bianca What is the magnetic sensor part number? Can you show a pic without a pencil blocking the layout?